# Benefits of having "Child born in the U. S. to a Chinese Parent" Visa?

Tags: passports, international-travel, us-citizens, china

I'm planning to travel to China and reviewed some of their visas to see which one will best benefit me -- my mom (US perm resident) and dad (US citizen) are Chinese descendant and live in the US, which leads me to the *Child born in the U. S. to a Chinese Parent* Visa.

I researched and have not come across anything stating an expiration or why I should choose this visa over the others.

Anyone who obtained this visa -- why or why not? Any advice will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Were you in fact born in the US?

Comment: Was your mom a permanent resident and was your dad a US citizen when you were born? Because if your mom was a Chinese citizen and didn't have permanent residency and your dad was already a US citizen when you were born, then you are a Chinese citizen and should apply for a Chinese Travel Document and not a Chinese visa (though this might only apply if you are a minor).

Comment: What is the purpose of your trip? Visiting family? Being a tourist? Also, are you a US citizen?

Comment: @user102008 I disagree with your advice, China does not accept dual citizenship and OP being a U.S. citizen makes him ineligible for Chinese citizenship, in fact claiming it would be sanctioned by Chinese authorities if they find out about the US citizenship and best advice is to not let them find out about it or renounce one citizenship.

Comment: @mts: There is no such thing as "accept" or "not accept" dual citizenship. Who has each country's citizenship is determined solely and independently by that country's law. Under Chinese law, the person under the circumstance I described does automatically have Chinese citizenship according to Chinese law as well as US citizenship according to US law. Both citizenships are automatic and involuntary; there is no "claim". And this is perfectly according to law; there is nothing to "find out" -- China knows that a child born in the US has US citizenship, but only recognizes the Chinese citizenship